# Prove that the logarithm function is an isomorphism of totally ordered abeligan groups of $\mathbb{P}$ onto the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The book of Abstract Algebra by Antonio Grillet, gives me the following example in the part of Valuations

> The logarithm function is an isomorphism of totally ordered abeligan groups of $\mathbb{P}$ onto the additive group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.

I would like to prove it, but I have no idea how to start, any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove:

- $\log : \mathbb P \to \mathbb R$ is a bijection.
- $\log$ is a homomorphism: $x,y \in \mathbb P \implies \log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$
- $\log$ is preserves order: $x,y  \in \mathbb P, x < y \implies \log(x) < \log(y)$

Answer (score 0):

To prove $F$ is homomorphism you must show that

$F:G(g,\star)\to H(h,*)\\
\forall g_1, g_2 \in G, F(g_1\star g_2) = F(g_1)*F(g_2)$

An isomorphism is a homomorphism with an inverse.